# Converting from for loop to while if fi loop UNIX

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to figure out how to convert the following for loop into  a while loop or until loop including if fi for UNIX  Here's the code...

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -gt 0 ] ; then 
  start=$1
 end=$3
 step=$2

 for x in `seq $start $step $end` ; do
  number $x
  done

else
 echo Enter at least one number on the command line.

fi
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```sh
(( x = start ))
until (( x > end ))
do
  number $x
  (( x += step ))
done
```

Comment: If `step` is `-1` this can give non-seq like results.

Answer (score 0):

For a loop like this, it's easiest to use the numeric-style `for` loop:

```
for ((x=start; x<=end; x+=step)); do
    number $x
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `seq` is good as it has some default values for `step` and `end` value. I added this to the `if` if only one, or two arguments are given. Also it handles the situation if the given argument are not numbers (default values are 0). Also an endless loop may encounter if `step` is zero. If You remove this checking it will work the same way as the `seq` version.

```
if [ $# -gt 0 ] ; then
  x=$(($1+0))
  end=$((${3:-$x}+0))
  step=$((${2:-1}+0))

  [ $step -eq 0 ] && echo "Step is zero!" && exit 1

  while [ $x -le $end -a $step -gt 0 -o $x -ge $end -a $step -lt 0 ]; do
    echo $x
    x=$((x+step))
  done

else
   echo Enter at least one number on the command line.
fi
```

Change `echo` to `number` in the while loop if you would like to use!

Examples:

```
$ ./e.sh 1    
1
$ seq 1
1
$ ./e.sh 1 1 3
1
2
3
$ seq 1 1 3
1
2
3
$ ./e.sh 1 -1 3
$ seq 1 -1 3
$ ./e.sh 3 -1 1
3
2
1
$ seq 3 -1 1
3
2
1
$ ./e.sh 1 0 1 
Step is zero!
$ seq 1 0 1|head 
1
1
1
... (endlessly)
$ ./e.sh 1 .1 1.2
./e.sh: line 3: 1.2+0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".2+0")
$ seq 1 .1 1.2
1.0
1.1
1.2
```

Bash arithmetic is not working with floating point numbers, but `seq` does. If You need this feature You could use the `x=$(echo $x + $step|bc)` format. Also `$((...))` should replaced by `$(...|bc)` like lines.

Comment: @user2329706: I'm happy if I could help. I suggest you to use the original `seq` version.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash 4 you can also do it like this:

```
for i in {$start..$stop..$step}; do
    echo $i
done
```